# Adding jssor to a c# project for a retail solution

Tags: jssor

I want to start by saying this is by far the best slider I have ever used! Thank you for such a great and beautiful solution!

The question I have is, can I include your solution in a retail c# project I am in the process of building? I would be happy to add credits/disclaimers/etc. to the project.

Customers would be buying the suite that I'm developing for a very specific application. Many plugins will be included with the proper permission.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Jssor Slider is definitely free!
You can include jssor slider in any project. You can even sell this software if you like.

See https://github.com/jssor/jquery-slider/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE.txt